# SBS 2011 Add Simple User for Scanner logon

Tags: network-share, user-accounts, windows-sbs-2011

Is there a better way to add a 'services' user account to SBS 2011 rather than use the 'Add User' wizard?

I have a scanner that wants to put scanned files on a SMB share. Since this scanner is unsecured, I want this scanner to have very limited access to the server - basically nothing other than the share itself. Using the wizards to create a user seems excessive to me - plus it creates links with various groups, shared folders, and mailboxes which I have to remove.

What is a simple, fast method to add a basic logon for use in SMB share only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Active Directory Users and Computers to create a user account for the scanner. Then grant that user account the appropriate permissions on the Share in question.

Comment: Is their any difference to creating the user in the '/MyBusiness/Users/SBSUsers' section or the '/Users' section in this instance?

Comment: The SBS specific OUs are intended for "interactive" user accounts, meaning users who are actual people who need to have SBS specific GPO's applied to them when they log on. This is a design and organizational construct that's specific to SBS. For your purposes you don't need to create the scanner user account in the SBS OU structure, you can create the user account in the standard Users container. In addition, users created manually in either container won't "inherit" any of the group memberships, disk quotas, etc. that would be inherent when creating them using the SBS console.

Comment: Also, take note that users created manually (not using the SBS console) won't show up in the SBS console.